# How to reset array field to empty in react form?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
                    form.setFieldsValue({content:[]});
```

content is a form field which can accept multiple values as an array of values
here content is an array.
And I want to set to an empty array for previously non-empty values .But when I use [] it crashes.
What should I do?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.